# error: “Creating default object from empty value”

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am following a tutorial that shows how to connect to MySql using laravel, but while trying to update the values I ran into an error, I did try to find something similar but failed at that.
The answers I found said that the object must be empty, but if I'm updating an existing values it's not empty.
A tutorial I am following https://www.webslesson.info/2018/01/insert-update-delete-in-mysql-table-laravel-tutorial.html

So I have a form that displays the data from database in a file **index.blade.php** with a **edit**, a form that displays specific user data in a fine **edit.blade.php** and the methods in **StudentController.php** file.

They look like this:

Table of the user data and the **edit** button **index.blade.php**

```
       <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($students as $row)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{$row['name']}}</th>
                    <th>{{$row['surname']}}</th>
                    <th><a href="{{action('StudentController@edit', $row['id'])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```

Form in the **edit.blade.php** file

```
      <form action="{{action('StudentController@update','$id')}}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{$student->name}}" placeholder="Enter first name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" value="{{$student->surname}}" placeholder="Enter last surname">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit">
            </div>

        </form>
```

And the methods in the **Student.Controller.php** file

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=> 'required',
        'surname'=> 'required'
    ]);
    $student = Student::find($id);
    $student->name=$request->get('name');
    $student->surname=$request->get('surname');
    $student->save();
    return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');
}
```

I get the error in **StudentController.php** file in the line: $student->name=$request->get('name');

Comment: Check whether your getting the values in the $request by using var_dump

Comment: check the edit.blade.php html source code, '$id' should be $id

Comment: @kenken9999 edited that, but I still get the error

Comment: what happen if change $request->get() to $request->input(), or you try dd($request->get('name'))

Comment: @kenken9999i changed to to input and now it works, not sure why, but thank you I guess :D

Comment: btw, better use route name instead of use action in your code, and how you assign the $id, after go the edit and index page in your browser, better check again all html source code, where showing incorrect href="" , form action="", input value="", ...etc

Answer (score 3):

You aren't verifying that a student was actually found.  If there is no record found, find will return null.

A common practice is to use findOrFail and let Laravel throw an exception if a record with $id is not found.

```
$student = Student::findOrFail($id);
```

Or you can handle it yourself:

```
$student = Student::find($id);
if (!$student) {
    return response(['error' => 'No student found']);
}
```

Comment: Yes, now I can see that no student has been found, but I don't really understand how. The table at the beginning shows only the saved students and the edit button passes that student id to the edit method. Am I passing the id incorrectly?

Comment: I changed $request->get() to $request->input() and now it works, but thank you for showing me that I was not verifying that a student exists. I will use that aswell.

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with your error.  The way you are using get/input are interchangeable, they both will do the same thing.

Comment: well, then I guess changes in the edit.blade.php HTML source code, '$id' to $id, solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah, that'd definitely cause it since there would be no literal `$id` record in your db.  Variables aren't parsed in single quotes.